# delete NA in some rows in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some rows in a text file have `NA` and i want to delete them .
when i used `isempty(strfind(l,'NA'))`, this deletes also strings have `NA` such as: 'RNASE' ,'GNAS'

*example*

```
0.552353744371678    NA

0.0121476193502138   ANG;RNASE

0.189489997218949    GNAS

0.0911820441646675    MYCL1
```

---

output:

```
0.0911820441646675     MYCL1
```

---

output expected:

```
0.0121476193502138   ANG;RNASE

0.189489997218949    GNAS

0.0911820441646675    MYCL1
```

Comment: Have you tried `isempty(strfind(l,' NA '))` ?

Comment: yes, i tried and i get unwanted output

Comment: So you need another condition for the case of "97647 NADG" for example.  something like "if I(strfind(l,' NA')+3) is a letter then don't delete it". (Sorry for no time for a complete answer...)

Comment: Thanks Adiel, but i tried and failed that's why i post it on here

Comment: i have posted the case which have NA and also deleted ,whether NA before or after 'RNASE ,GNAS'

Comment: it was unexpected result when i finish this code !!

Comment: i appreciate any help !.

Comment: Is `NA` always at the end of the string when you want to remove it?

Comment: No i have some cells have only NA , but some cells have GNAS , RNASE,

Comment: as you see the command which i used delete everything have NA whether alone or inside strings .

Comment: en brief, i just want to delete NA which means 'Not Available' just it ; and keep other strings that have NA inside is ok .

Comment: suppose `I` is a line that you want to delete. what you get for `I(strfind(l,' NA')+3)` ?

Comment: plz, i can't understand the first character you post .? thanks

Comment: I(strfind(l,' NA')+3)!?

Comment: Exactly. That will give you that character that comes after "NA" in a string that begins with "NA", where actually you have a problem. If it is another letter it will give it. If it's the end of line, I would want to know what the output is.

Comment: i tried it but still same problem

Comment: What do you mean same problem? what is the output of your first line as `l` to that command??

Comment: Sorry, I replaced `l` with `I`. The command is `l(strfind(l,' NA')+3)`

Comment: yeah, i try that on my code but no result when it found NA still deleted!!!

Comment: I can't suggest what you should write in your code, because I don't know your code... It really shouldn't work. I just ask, meanwhile, I understand that you loop each raw? when your first raw of the text in your question is the `l` of your code- what do you get if you type `l(strfind(l,' NA')+3)` ?

Comment: I want to know it because: 1. I don't know the format of the text file, 2. I don't know how you read it to matlab, 3. This is actually the line that you want to remove

Comment: when i first type l(strfind(l,' NA')+3) after l=fgetl(fid); i get the first row of my file in workspace browser and ans= ' ' in command window

Comment: i have a very large textfile which have float numbers and strings such as 0.235588 KNAS 0.569899 0.489966

Comment: i read it into MATLAB  line by line using while ~feof(fid)   l=l=fgetl(fid) end

Comment: @ Adiel sorry if i bother you bro,

Comment: Ok, that what I meant. Let's try it more simple, you want to remove only rows and all the rows that end with " NA"? what the output of `l(end-2:end)`, after you call `fgetl` for the first line?

Comment: I think that you can just change your condition to `~strcmp(l(end-2:end),' NA')`

Comment: could you explain it for me , is it compare and remove or what bcz i have to add isempty

Comment: No, you don't need `isempty`, the `~strcmp` replace it. It states the criteria for the lines that you want to preserve as they not ending with the specific string " NA" [space-N-A]. Am I correct that it can describe what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using single regexp I do not know how to find

```
"NA that does not have any alphanumeric character before or after".
```

I mean, it is easy if you know there will be at least one other character before and after:

```
ind = regexp(str, '[^A-Za-z_]NA[^A-Za-z_]'); %Or something similar, depending what exactly can and cannot be there.
```

However, this string requires characters before and after and will not match single 'NA' by itself.

That is to say, I am nearly certain suitable regexp exists, I just don't know it :)

What I would do is (assuming strl = single line with text you are deciding to keep or remove, that might have multiple `NA`).

```
ind = regexp(strl, 'NA'); % This finds all NA in the string.
removestr = true;
for i = 1 : length(ind)
   if (ind == 1 || any(regexp(strl(ind-1), '[^A-Za-z_]'))) ... &&
      && (ind+1 == length(strl) || any(regexp(strl(ind+2), '[^A-Za-z_]')))
      disp('This is maybe the string to remove - if there are no wrong NA's later')
   else
      removestr = false;
      break; % stop checking in this loop, this string is to keep.
   end
end
if (removestr)
   disp('Remove string')
end
```

Conditions in `if` are a bit overkill and quite slow, but should work. If you don't require checking for multiple `NA` in a single line, simply omit `for` loop.

Comment: Thank  Adiel i appreciate your help, but i can't yet fix it , what about if we use strcmp

Comment: This is not mine answer